# center horizontally and vertically paragraph inside div

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

how i can center horizontally and vertically the paragraph inside the div , i came to this result

```css
.Benefits {
  min-height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<section class="Benefits">
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum n</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: align-items: center;

Comment: which paragraph do you want to center? You have 4 of them. Or do you want to center everything, like the whole div directly beneath .Benefits?

Comment: Please give use more information about what do you want to achieve

Comment: i want to make the Paragraph of each div center vertically and horizontally

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.Benefits div {
  min-height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="Benefits">
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum n</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have noted in my CSS what's going on here:

I think you're best using two cases of `display: flex`. One horizontally, one vertically.

```css
.Benefits {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1248px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* centers container */
    padding: 10px; /* this combined with the margin in the divs will make the margins appear consistent */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row; /* sort into rows */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
}

    .Benefits div {
        width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
        margin: 10px; /* space between boxes */
        padding: 20px; /* space inside boxes */
        box-sizing: border-box; /* calculates border and padding in width */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column; /* sort into columns */
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-grow: 1; /* forces singular div that falls beneath to be full width */

        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }
        @media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
            .Benefits div {
                width: calc((100% / 2) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
            .Benefits div {
                width: 100%; /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
            }
        }

        .Benefits div h1 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<section class="Benefits">

    <div>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum n</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Yes, anyone can vote how they want on any answer. I guess they downvoted yours as you use prefixed `display: *-flex` but didn't on the other flex properties, and when not, it is completely meaning less to prefix in the first place